# How to fix a sum formula that changes ranges

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub formu 
    Range(“d” & Rows.count).end(xlUp).offset(2,0).formular1c1 = “=sum(R[-9]c:r[-1]c)”
End sub
```

Currently this is my formula but it changes on a weekly basis so I t could be R[-14]c:r[-1]c the next week or R[-6]c:r[-1]c the next week. How do I get my formula to change weekly so I don’t have to manually re sum the cell?

Comment: What is causing the change? And when it changes, how do you know how to adjust your formula? Basically, you'll have to incorporate that knowledge into a VBA routine to automagically determine what range to include to get your sum.

Comment: It changes each week depending on how much data is that week so the range that needs to be added together would be Range(“d” & OHR & “:d” & OTR). How would I put that in a sum formula?

Comment: See if [this information](https://turbofuture.com/computers/Use-OFFSET-and-COUNTA-to-create-dynamic-ranges-with-automatically-updating-formulas-in-Excel-2007-and-Excel-2010) helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will check it out

Answer (score 2):

Say the following would be your current weeks data:

[image]

The following code would add a formula in the cell below the last cell:

```
Sub formu()

Dim lr As Long
With Formulas
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(lr + 1, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R[-" & lr & "]c:r[-" & lr - (lr - 1) & "]c)"
End With

End Sub
```

Whereas the sheet reference is the sheet codename containing the data. Output:

[image]

The formula in that cell is currently:

```
=SUM(R[-10]C:R[-1]C)
```

---

You can find a sheet's `CodeName` in the project explorer and give it a meaningfull name to reference directly :)

Comment: When I entered in this formula it gave me a run time error

Comment: @djh006, there is too little information on both what you are actually trying and what goes wrong implementing this code. It's too hard to just guess what might go wrong. I suggest you to edit your question, and read [ask] a question with a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for answer I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is important to know if your weekly report always put the information in te same order. For example all the numbers start in the `Range("A2")`. If that the case i recomend you to work whit TagNames. Asuming that the data you need to sum start in the `Range("A2")`

```
Dim Col as integer 
Dim sRow, eRow as long 's = start, e = end

Col = Range("A2").Column 'Col = 1
sRow = Range("A2").Row  'sRow = 2
eRow = Range("A2").Rnd(xlDown).Row 'eRow = row of the last cell with information to sum

Range(Cells(sRow,Col),Cells(eRow,Col)).Name = "range2Sum" 'Yo assign a tagname

'The you can use what you have done

Range(“d” & Rows.count).end(xlUp).offset(2,0).formula = “=sum(range2Sum)” 'use that tagname that is visible in excel
```